# RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in longlong_scalars

Tags: python, pandas

## What I'm trying to do

I want to report the weekly rejection rate for multiple users. I use a for loop to go through a monthly dataset to get the numbers for every user. The final dataframe, `rates`, should look something like:

[The end product, `rates`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzV7W.png)

## Description

I have an initial dataframe (`numbers`), that contains only the ACCEPT, REJECT and REVIEW numbers, where I added these rows and columns:

- **Rows**: Grand Total, Rejection Rate
- **Columns**: Grand Total

Here's how `numbers` look like:

```
|---|--------|--------|--------|--------|-------------|
|   | Week 1 | Week 2 | Week 3 | Week 4 | Grand Total | 
|---|--------|--------|--------|--------|-------------|
| 0 |  994   |  699   |  529   |   877  |     3099    | 
|---|--------|--------|--------|--------|-------------|
| 1 |   27   |   7    |    8   |   13   |      55     |
|---|--------|--------|--------|--------|-------------|
| 2 |  100   |   86   |   64   |   107  |      357    |
|---|--------|--------|--------|--------|-------------|
| 3 |  1121  |  792   |  601   |  997   |    3511     |
|---|--------|--------|--------|--------|-------------|
```

The indexes represent the following values:

- 0 - ACCEPT
- 1 - REJECT
- 2 - REVIEW
- 3 - TOTAL (Accept+Reject+Review)

I wrote 2 pre-defined functions:

1. `get_decline_rates(df)`: The get the decline rates by week in the `numbers` dataframe.
2. `copy(empty_df, data)`: To transfer all data to a new dataframe with "double" headers (for reporting purposes).

Here's my code where I add rows and columns to `numbers`, then re-format it:

```
# Adding "Grand Total" column and rows
totals = numbers.sum(axis=0) # column sum
numbers = numbers.append(totals, ignore_index=True)
grand_total = numbers.sum(axis=1) # row sum
numbers.insert(len(numbers.columns), "Grand Total", grand_total)

# Adding "Rejection Rate" and re-indexing numbers
decline_rates = get_decline_rates(numbers)
numbers = numbers.append(decline_rates, ignore_index=True)
numbers.index = ["ACCEPT","REJECT","REVIEW","Grand Total","Rejection Rate"]

# Creating a new df with report format requirements 
final = pd.DataFrame(0, columns=numbers.columns, index=["User A"]+list(numbers.index))
final.ix["User A",:] = final.columns

# Copying data from numbers to newly formatted df
copy(final,numbers) 

# Append final df of this user to the final dataframe
rates = rates.append(final)
```

I'm using **Python 3.5.2** and **Pandas 0.19.2**. If it helps, here's how the initial dataset looks like:

[Data format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiD04.png)

I do a resampling on the date column to get the data by week.

## What's going wrong

Here's the funny part - the code runs fine and I get all the required information in `rates`. However, I'm seeing this warning message:

> RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in longlong_scalars

If i break down the code and run it line by line, this message does not appear. Even the message looks weird (what does *longlong_scalars* even mean?) Does anyone know what this warning message mean, and what's causing it?

**UPDATE:**

I just ran a similar script that takes in exactly the same input and produces a similar output (except I get daily rejection rates instead of weekly). I get the same Runtime warning, except more information is given:

> RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in longlong_scalars
>
> rej_rate = str(int(round((col.ix[1 ]/col.ix[3 ])*100))) + "%"

I suspect something must have gone wrong when I was trying to calculate the decline rates with my pre-defined function, `get_decline_rates(df)`. Could it be due to the dtype of the values? All columns on the input df, `numbers`, are `int64`.

Here's the code for my pre-defined function (the input, `numbers`, can be found under **Description**):

```
# Description: Get rejection rates for all weeks.
# Parameters: Pandas Dataframe with ACCEPT, REJECT, REVIEW count by week.
# Output: Pandas Series with rejection rates for all days in input df.
def get_decline_rates(df):
    decline_rates = []
    for i in range(len(df.columns)):
        col = df.ix[:,i]

        try:
            rej_rate = str(int(round((col[1]/col[3])*100))) + "%"
        except ValueError:
            rej_rate = "0%"

        decline_rates.append(rej_rate)

    return pd.Series(decline_rates, index=df.columns)
```

Comment: What does your input look like?  Welcome to Stackoverflow!  I would help a great deal if you followed this article on asking questions.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @ScottBoston Hi there! Thanks for sharing the article, my question was not complete. I've edited the post to include how the data input looks. The complete dataset can be accessed here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9aicFjOCOKhR1VtZTVqa0FsM0U/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 12):

I had the same RuntimeWarning, and after looking into the data, it was because of a null-division. I did not have the time to look into your sample, but you could look around id=0, or some other records, where null-division or such could occur.

Comment: That was exactly my problem! In a function I was calling, I had performed a calculation with the sum of a list, without considering that the list might be all 0s. (This is a seriously unhelpful error message; I wonder why the 'division by zero' exception wasn't thrown.) Thank you!

Comment: It was the same problem for me. Dividing by 0 causes this error.