# How to get row by row values for the dataframe? I'm trying to convert this dax code to python and receive the same answer

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, powerbi, dax

I've got this dax code.

```
Inclusion_Expected = 
    VAR _item_number = Source_With_Trace_ID[Item_Number]
    VAR _cast_date = Source_With_Trace_ID[Casting_Date]
    VAR _start_date = _cast_date - 365
    VAR _inclusions = 
        CALCULATE(
            SUM(Source_With_Trace_ID[Inclusion]),
            FILTER(Source_With_Trace_ID,
                    Source_With_Trace_ID[Item_Number] = _item_number
                    && Source_With_Trace_ID[Casting_Date] >= _start_date
                    && Source_With_Trace_ID[Casting_Date] < _cast_date
            )
        )

    VAR _closed = 
        CALCULATE(
            SUM(Source_With_Trace_ID[Closed]),
            FILTER(Source_With_Trace_ID,
            Source_With_Trace_ID[Item_Number] = _item_number
            && Source_With_Trace_ID[Casting_Date] >= _start_date
            && Source_With_Trace_ID[Casting_Date] < _cast_date
            )
        )

    VAR _inclusion_scrap_rate = DIVIDE(_inclusions, _closed)

    RETURN _inclusion_scrap_rate
```

And I want to convert it to python. This is what I have right now, however each row contains the same value. Instead of a different value for each row.

```
_item_number = df2['Item_Number']
_cast_date = df2['Casting_Date']
_start_date =  _cast_date - pd.DateOffset(days=365)

df2['inclusions_group'] = df2[
    (df2['Item_Number'] == _item_number) &
    (df2['Casting_Date'] >= _start_date)
]['Inclusion'].sum()

df2['closed_group'] = df2[
    (df2['Item_Number'] == _item_number) &
    (df2['Casting_Date'] >= _start_date)
]['Closed'].sum()

df2['expected_inclusion_scrap_rate'] = df2['inclusions_group'] / df2['closed_group']
```

I need some direction on how to get the scrap_rate for each row.
Thank you for the help!

Comment: In your code, `_item_number` is not a single value but is an entire Series (the whole column). Same with _cast_date and _start_date. So, in your next piece of code, all the conditions are going to evaluate as True no matter what. You are checking `df2['Item_Number'] == _item_number`, which is True because you just set it as such a few lines earlier. In addition, when you have the `.sum()` on the dataframe, your result is just a single number. So you are setting `df['inclusion_group'] = n`; this will set the value to that same `n` for every single row.

Comment: And I don't know DAX well at all - if you describe in plain text what you are trying to do, it might be clearer (at least to me).

Comment: @scotscotmcc I have a calculated column named Inclusion_Expected. I set _item_number, _cast_date equal to the Series (the columns in my table) and a constant _start_date to do some comparisons later. Next I make a variable _inclusions that returns a table. The calculate function is a way to do an aggregation while doing some type of filtering throughout the table, and returns a single value. For _inclusions, a sum aggregation is made, and I want to filter row by row in the filter statement.

Comment: @scotscotmcc  It starts at the first row and checks the comparisons, then the next, to the last row of the table. (I'm assuming like a for loop?) Finally the closed variable does the same thing, except for another series. Finally the variable Inclusion_scrap_rate is created. To take each row's _inclusions divided by each rows _closed. I'm not too familiar with DAX as well, so I hope I explained it enough.

Comment: Another update, my Inclusion and Closed series are binary columns (0, or 1).

Comment: Inclusion and Closed are supposed to be binary? Or they are erroneously coming out as binary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work, but hard to know without test data...

```py
def my_func(row,df:pd.DataFrame) -> float:
    '''Use with df.apply(my_func,axis=1,df=df)'''

    item_num = row['Item_Number']
    cast_date = row['Casting_Date']
    start_date = cast_date - pd.DateOffset(days=365)

    inclusion_group = df[
        (df['Item_Number'] == item_num) &
        (df['Casting_Date'] >= start_date)
    ]['Inclusion'].sum()

    closed_group = df[
        (df['Item_Number'] == item_num) &
        (df['Casting_Date'] >= start_date)
    ]['Closed'].sum()

    output = inclusion_group / closed_group
    return output

df2['expected_inclusion_scrap_rate'] = df2.apply(my_func,axis=1,df=df2)
```

As I said in the comments, it looks like part of your problem is that you are trying to do some things on a per-row basis but are instead accidentally doing them for the whole dataframe.

This code works with `df.apply(...)`, which runs a function across either a row or column of the dataframe. In this case, we call it with `axis=1` to do it by row.

We still need to pass the whole dataframe into the apply because part of your calculation is filtering the whole df based on the values in this row, which is why the df is also an argument.

Comment: I think the df.apply() is exactly what I need. I do need a row by row aggregation. I will give this a try and let you know. Thank you for the suggestions!

Comment: I am now receiving this error: " unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int' ". I'm not sure why this is erroring out? I'm using the Item Number series (which is an obj dtype) and summing the inclusion and closed series which are int series.

Comment: do you have any missing parenthesis? the `&` operator is in here for making the inclusion_group and closed_group values, and what it should be doing is a comparison on `TRUE & FALSE` or `TRUE & TRUE`, on booleans. The error is saying that it isn't doing it on booleans, but that instead, in at least once of the calculations, it is doing it on str and int. Implies to me that `(df['Item_Number'] == item_num)` is somehow returning a str instead of a bool

Comment: I'm not missing any parenthesis. It looks like all of my comparisons are giving me an error. I took out the df2['Item Number] = item_number and now it's giving me this error. TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'DatetimeArray' and 'DatetimeArray'

Comment: strange... not sure how much more help I can be from across the web. I'd suggest stepping through the function with a debugger at this point and seeing what it is comparing, what they are, and what you want them to be...

Comment: Something I realized I didn't have was parenthesis around each comparison. Is that necessary when using multiple comparisons? After I put them in, I ran it and it didn't error out, however I got this warning, ipykernel_4800\180890033.py:24: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in longlong_scalars
  expected_inclusion = _inclusions / _closed. And the cell has been running for about 5 minutes.

Comment: you do want the parenthesis around each individual comparison, yes. my one-search on the error suggests people got it from divide-by-zero issues https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43216185/runtimewarning-invalid-value-encountered-in-longlong-scalars, so you'll want to make sure that closed_group isn't 0. might be running long because it can't handle that error but doesn't bail properly? or too much data, but if powerbi can do it more quickly than this shouldn't take 5+ minutes...